# i18n in build process (or compiling one template HTML to i18n HTMLs)

Tags: java, internationalization, client-side

i'm working on a project which needs to support internationalization.
the solution we thought of is:

1. create HTML templates with placeholders for language (i.e. home.html).
2. create an i18n directory with files such as: "language_en_GB.json".
3. on the build process have them merged together to create an output HTML. the output file will sit on a language based directory (such as "views/en_GB/home.html" or "views/fr_CA/home.html").

so basically this:

```
<h1>{{i18n_welcome}}</h1>
<h2>{{userName}}</h2>
```

merged with this:

```
 {
      welcome:"Welcome!"
  }
```

will become this during a build proccess:

```
   <h1>Welcome!</h1>
   <h1>{{userName}}</h1>
```

i have a few question and appriciate your input.

1. is this a good approach for i18n?
2. do you know of a templating engine that does that i18n process well?
3. is there a solution for client side "baking". i would like a UI developer to be able to bake localy as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are several frameworks that support i18n out of the box depending on your needs and what you are currently using in your code.  As a pure templating engine, you can take a look at [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) or [Freemarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/).  For a more complete framework, you can look at [Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/) and [Spring example](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-internationalization-i18n-localization-tutorial-example/) and [Struts](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/) and [Struts2 example](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-i18n-or-localization-example/).

There are, of course, numerous other options as well.  I'm just listing four of the most popular that I've seen people use.

Basically, for any of the frameworks, you create resource bundles for each language (named using the language for the specific bundle.  Ex: language_en_GB.properties).  So your thought process is pretty much in line.  Basically you start with your html file and include your placeholder.  In your resource bundle for each language, you specify what the string is supposed to be. After that, the framework does the merging on the fly for you, using the appropriate resource bundle for the language in question.

So you're pretty much on the right track - it all becomes a question of integrating properly with your framework and leveraging it to do the merging instead of doing it during your build pipeline.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. i understand those are server-side framework. we do the internationlazition this way today - using jsps. my thought was - as so many things are planned to happen in our build process (lessCSS becomes css, js files are minimized and gzipped, backbone models and views are merged into one module file, etc.) why not having the i18n process there too? this way you have only static htmls in your system. is it a logical solution?

Comment: I guess the question is why you are looking to make this more difficult to maintain? You will now generate hundreds of static htmls (depending on number of html pages and/or locales). Additionally, you end up with things that are custom and non-standard - makes for more difficult maintenance in the future by others.  I suppose you'll end up writing a servlet that will map html name to html_lang name (which defeats the CDN idea).  Otherwise you'll not be able to link between different pages, or will have to ensure that all links have i18n extensions to them, which gets ugly.

Comment: i thought that the build process can transform a template for the templates directory into a page in a i18n directory (i.e. pages/en/home.html)

Answer (score 1):

You failed to provide the necessary details, so I can't really answer your question. I can only say that what you plan seems to be another wheel re-invention (but not as round as original one).

There are certain i18n best practices. In Java world it usually mean using Resource Bundles (in form of properties files) and some mechanism like JSTL to translate them when the page is being rendered. This is the best approach, as you won't need to re-compile anything to introduce the support for another language.

If you care about providing support for client-side scripts, it is usually done by writing out some array from the web page and accessing it on the client side. I think this is the most common solution. Another would be having some web service to provide you with translations and read it via XHR (i.e. AJAX), but that may be problematic. Anyway, you need to push the translations from the server side to the client side somehow.
And of course you need to read them from resource bundles.

From what you wrote it seems that you want to build some kind of static web page, backed by the application server (thus static web pages compilation). If I guessed correctly, honestly using Java for it is a bit overkill. You'd better go with some CMS software like Joomla, Drupal or jEase.

Comment: thank you for your thorough answer. i felt i might be reinventing a wheel - i don't want that. my thought was if i already have micro templates in my system and a client-side MVC (backbone) that serves those micro-templates, why not mix language placeholder and data placeholder and pre-compile the templates during build process. i will end up with a pure static website that i can put on a CDN (lower costs and easier setup). is it logical? is there a "wheel" for that?

Comment: Basically, if what you do is mostly static pages, that is you won't have too many things generated dynamically, this approach looks promising. I don't think anybody did it like this, so you'll be kind of pioneer. However, I see few drawbacks in your solution, mostly related to Localization: 1. How to deploy new language without rebuilding the whole thing. 2. How to fix specific Localization defect (i.e. incorrect translation, misalignments, required style modifications). These are things to consider as the maintenance might be problematic.

Comment: @PawełDyda The other issue that may be problematic is the actual URLs will show the locale (which may or may not be desired) and all the links will need to have the locales appended as well.  Finally, I can see this becoming very difficult to test during development as the only way to validate that all the links are working is to build and deploy everything each time.

Comment: @Pawel - i agree i would need to rebuild for new languages. for locale i thought of using jquery.glob.

Comment: @ericB - you're points are valid. for the URL issue - as we're using backbonejs's router the locale won't be visible for the user.